# JFrame not resizing with JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

I am making a minesweeper program, and I need to implement a feature where the user can choose to resize the grid that the mines are on. I've finished this, but when I make a larger board the JFrame doesn't get any larger, with it.

This is the method that happens when the user wants to resize the board

```
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    if(e.getSource() == quitButton && e.getButton() == 1){
        System.exit(0);
    }
    // if I hit the reset size button this happens
    if(e.getSource() == setDimension){
        for (int r = 0; r < size; r++)
            for (int c = 0; c < size; c++){
                gameBoard.remove(board[r][c]); // removes the buttons from the board
            }
        inputSizeAndMines(); // lets the user choose the size and amount of mines
        game = new MineSweeperGame(size, mines); // remakes the game 
        setBoard(); // adds new buttons based on what the user entered
        displayBoard(); // makes visuals for the board
        revalidate();
        repaint();
    }
```

This is the class that adds the panel to a JFrame

```
public class MineSweeper {


    /**********************************
     * Main class that does everything
     **********************************/
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("MineSweeper");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        MineSweeperPanel panel = new MineSweeperPanel();
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

}
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call `pack` on the frame again once you have re-calculated the preferred size of the panel

Comment: How do I do that when the frame is in a separate class?

Comment: Your `frame` is `static`, which to my mind isn't a good idea or you could use [`SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#getWindowAncestor(java.awt.Component))

Comment: Oh, that's my bad, I was trying something else that didn't work and forgot to change it. Does that make a difference? Thanks, for your help by the way

Comment: It means that anything can access you frame reference from anywhere...but given I can use `SwingUtilities` to do the same thing its less of any issue.  The only problem comes if you change the reference (accidentally or otherwise) or want more than one game frame

Comment: I made an edit in my where I don't have the JFrame as static or as an instance variable. Is there anything different I could do off of that?

Comment: You could take a look at [Initial Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html), then you just need to use `SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor` to find the `Window`  that the component resides within and call `pack`

Comment: Makes a nice change ;)